# How to make hierarchical URLs

Tags: php, content-management-system, blogs

Im building an application with PHP, similar to any CMS we have(wordpress, joomla), not such big one, but just my custom script to manage some blogging requirements, so what I do is, I do generate complete URL in SEO friendly manner like

`www.domain.com/category1/category2/category3/page/`

I can do this by joining relations from Page to domain all the way like

`page->category3->category2->category1->domain`

I did this but I feel i am overloading the server and some how I feel my code is in efficient, in the way, I need to execute 3 queries to get this page hierarchy, for fetching all 3 categories addresses(slugs), so I am looking is there any efficient way to achieve the same in better manner?

Comment: There are available a previous posting at `SO` like this topic. `NNicols` has explained nicely in his post about this issue, do you have time to read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609976/how-to-implement-hierarchical-cms-sites)